# Links opened by left-click in IE8 take forever compared to middle-mouse button

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

When I use the middle mouse button to open a link in a new tab, it works instantly. However, if I left-click the link to open it normally, IE8 freezes for about 5 seconds before the popup window opens.

I'm sick of all the slowness and the glitchiness and the memory hogging, and I just want it to work as well as all the other browsers out there. Anybody else experiencing this and have any tips?

Note: It's not the Java SSV helper or the Skype addon (because I have those disabled). I'm looking for some advanced solutions that I can try.

(God, I hate IE8, but I'm a loyal Microsoft follower so I refuse to switch to Firefox. )

Comment: IE9 is coming, so you may have more or less reason to hate it!  :)

Comment: No need to switch to Firefox. Chrome FTW! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Reposting a link that was unfortunately obfuscated:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/07/18/how-to-make-ie-open-new-tabs-faster.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but I've already disabled problematic addons and it still happens even in no-addons mode. I'm looking for something advanced, like a registry tweak or something. Also, I love your blog :)